# Not able to find the id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to plot a graph inside a div which is dynamically created. A string of HTML divs is passed from the backend and then it is appended to the `comparison_widgets` div. Then a call to a function is made which needs to plot a graph(Highcharts) inside that div.

But when it goes to the function it says 
`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #id_Asia/Pacific_NorthAmerica
throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );`

It is not able to find the id, i guess. Where I'm going wrong?

Here result[1] is the **div string**, ie

```
<div id="widget_Asia/Pacific_NorthAmerica" class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
<div class="portlet-header ui-corner-all">
<span class="close right">x</span>
Asia / Pacific_North America
</div>
<div id="id_Asia/Pacific_NorthAmerica" class="portlet-content"></div>
</div>
```

result[2] is `id_Asia/Pacific_NorthAmerica`

and result[0] is the data that needs to be plotted on the graph.

**The AJAX FUNCtion**

```
 $.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "/dashboard/",
    data : { 'comparison_widget_id' : comparison_widget_id,'level_id':level_id,  },
    success: function(result){
        $("#comparison_widgets").append(result[1]);
        var div_id = "id_"+result[2];
        comparison_chart(div_id,result[0]);
        }
  });


function comparison_chart(div_id,result) {

  var MAXPOINTS = 20;
  var level_number = 0;
  Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
          useUTC: false,
      }
  });

$("#"+div_id).highcharts({
    chart: {
      events: {
      load: function() {

          // set up the updating of the chart each second
          var series = this.series[0];


          setInterval(function() {
              var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                  y = Math.random();
              if(series.data.length > MAXPOINTS){
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);  
              }
              else{
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);
              }



          },5000);
      },
  }

    },
    title: {
        text: 'Energy Chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var s;
                s = this.y + 'kWh';
            return s;
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Live Data',
        data: result[0],
        showInLegend: true,

    }, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: result[2],
        center: [90, 20],
        size: 125,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        point :{
          events:{
            click : function(){
              level_number = level_number + 1;
              $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type : 'POST',
                url : '/dashboard/',
                data : {'name': this.name, 'level_number' : level_number},
                success: function(result){
                  comparison_chart(result);
                }
              });
            }
          }
        },
    }]
  });
}
```

Comment: You should not use '/' character inside element ID. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('#widget_Asia\\/Pacific_NorthAmerica')`